# How to pass data from Dropwizard authenticator back to application

Tags: java, dropwizard, java-11

I have a dropwizard application with a basic custom authenticator:

```
import java.util.Optional;

import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthenticationException;
import io.dropwizard.auth.Authenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;

public class DropwizardTestAuthenticator implements Authenticator<BasicCredentials, User> {

    @Override
    public Optional<User> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) throws AuthenticationException {

        if(customLib.authenticate(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.password())) { 
            // customLib.getAssociatedGroups(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.password());
            // cache groups for later use
            return Optional.of(new User(credentials.getUsername(), new HashSet<String>()));
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

The custom lib authenticates with AD.  I'd like to user another function from the custom lib to query AD for all groups to witch the user is a member.  The a password, so this is the only place I can call the getAssociatedGroups() function. The normal dropwizard authorizor will not work because the pw is not available.  I cant change the lib so I'll live with the limitation, but I can't figure out how to pass the user group data back to the core application.  I see that dependency injection is limited with Guice (only new objects) so that won't work.  The authorizor is instantiated by a custom extension of the DW DefaultServerFactory, so I tried passing properties using the JerseyEnvironment to which it has access, but I get a "you cant set properties in this context" error.

What I want:

- After a user is authenticated, also query the lib for associated groups
- Cache list of groups such that it is available to core business logic

Any ideas?

DW: 1.3.8
Java: 11

Comment: `dropwizard` is using Jersey which has HK2 as dependency injection engine. Have you explored this path? https://javaee.github.io/hk2/